# secure data transfer between chrome extension and native messaging host

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

The data exchange between Chrome extension and Native messaging host happens through std io.

Questions :

- How secure is this data transfer ?
- Is there a way for man-in-middle attack for such data transfer ?

Comment: Wow. the words are exactly the same. I'm not sure how that happened. I did look for this question before adding it.

Comment: I edited that question to use your wording, that's how ;) I mean, there's no need to have 2 separate questions, but yours is better stated.

Comment: Ahh. :-) . Follow up : The answer to your question doesn't completely answer the question. Irrespective of the hacker got onto the user session I'm curious to know can they read stdin/out data ? If so how ?

Comment: Technically, no, that's not my question. But no matter. Also, you now have sufficient rep to comment.